# Call ItemTouchHelper.onChildDraw() manually to swipe item on RecyclerView

Tags: android, canvas, android-recyclerview, swipe, dismiss

I have been struggling with this some time and so far I haven't been able to find any answer for this.

I have a recyclerview with an ItemTouchHelper to detect swipe actions. When I swipe an item in the recyclerview, I am using `ItemTouchHelper.onChildDraw()` to draw some stuff behind the viewholder which is being swiped.

So far so good.

Now I have a button which should swipe an item, so I am trying to call `ItemTouchHelper.onChildDraw()` manually so I can reuse the code I have done so far.

The problem is that `ItemTouchHelper.onChildDraw()` takes a `Canvas` as a parameter, which according to the documentation is *"The canvas which RecyclerView is drawing its children"*. Is there a way to get that canvas from the `RecyclerView`? If I do `ItemTouchHelper.onChildDraw(new Canvas()...)` the code gets executed but nothing is being drawn behind the viewholder because it is obviously not the same canvas the recyclerview is using... Perhaps is there a way to **set** a canvas to be used by the recyclerview?

Thanks for the ideas in forehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I solved this was creating a custom view extending RecyclerView and saving the canvas object generated by android onDraw(). Then I could fetch the same canvas whenever I want to trigger the swiping manually by code.

```
public class CanvasRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {
    private Canvas mCanvas;

    public CanvasRecyclerView(final Context context) { super(context); }

    public CanvasRecyclerView(final Context context, @Nullable final AttributeSet attrs) { super(context, attrs); }

    @Override public void onDraw(final Canvas c) {
        mCanvas = c;
        super.onDraw(c);
    }

    public Canvas getCanvas() {
        return mCanvas;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

**Update**

To swipe the RecyclerView item manually, something like this can be done (warning, very hackish):

```
private fun swipeCard(direction: Int) {
    val visibleChild = (recyclerView?.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
    val holder = recyclerView?.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(visibleChild) ?: return

    val dX = if (direction == LEFT) -holder.itemView.width else holder.itemView.width

    val translation = SwipeAnimation(dX.toFloat()) //your translation here
    translation.setSwipingElements(recyclerView, touchHelper, holder)
    emptyView.startAnimation(translation)
}
```

`emptyView` is a View that needs to be existing outside the RecyclerView with the ViewHolders you want to swipe. I couldn't figure out how to swipe the view inflated in the ViewHolder, so what I did was to swipe a view (invisible) that was located on the screen and then pass along the transition `dX` values to the `ItemtouchHelper.onChildDraw()`.

Comment: Update: This doesn't work if you use the recyclerView within a ConstraintLayout.